# Postgres Query to remove regex from URL?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a bunch of URLs in my Postgres table with this format:

/blog/post?id=34331824c1866ffb&**extraParam=23232**&id2=2

/blog/post?id=343fb434343&**extraParam=XXXX**&id2=2

How do I write a query to return the URLs without the extraParam values?

IE. I want this returned:

/blog/post?id=34331824c1866ffb&id2=2

/blog/post?id=343fb434343&id2=2

Comment: `(\/blog\/post\?id=)([\w\d]*)&(?:\w*.*)(&id\d)(=\d)` something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/MNWcgm/1) ? You can just concatenate the groups after the you execute the regex

Comment: You could to do it without regexp: `concat_ws('&', split_part(x,'&',1), split_part(x,'&',3))` where `x` is your field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_replace to achieve what you need.
**Syntax**: regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ])

Here is an example:
SELECT regexp_replace('abc&def&ghi','&.*&','&')
**Result**: abc&ghi

You can refer the below link for further reading:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after regexp_replace, but replace with a null value

Like this:

```
CASE
 WHEN column ~ 'regex'
 THEN
 REGEXP_REPLACE(column, 'regex', '') END) AS column_processed
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN url_column ~ '\?.*extraParam=.*&'
            THEN regexp_replace(url_column, 'extraParam=.*&', '')
            WHEN url_column ~ '\?.*extraParam=.*'
            THEN regexp_replace(url_column, 'extraParam=.*', '')
            ELSE url_column
            END
```

Probably query could be more accurate, I'm a newbie

Comment: This doesn't handle the case in which "extraParam" is the last parameter.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson you're right and I mentioned this in my comment. This handles the examples from the original post

Comment: @JonathanJacobson however I fixed this, it should work now